# How to left-align a checkboxfield in sencha touch 2?

Tags: checkbox, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, fieldset

I'm just wondering if anyone has been able to successfuly left-align a checkbox field inside a fieldset; my attempts are failing.

```
{
xtype : 'checkboxfield',
name : 'remember',
label : 'Store information',
style: 'float: left'
}
```

An image is better:

[image]

Comment: ty for the uploaded image. It clarifies your question.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to align the `checkboxfield` to `left`. Check out the below code ...

```
 {
    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
    name : 'tomato',
    value: 'tomato',
    checked: true,
    label: 'Tomato',
    labelWidth: '70%',
    labelAlign: 'right'
 }
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: Well; i can do this as well; the goal is to have the checkbox on the 'right' of the label, not the label on the right.

Comment: What do you mean by checkbox on the right of label? By default, it's always at the right of the label? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Here is checkboxfield default css (touch 2.2.1 ):
`

```
.x-checkmark-base, .x-field-checkbox .x-field-mask::after, .x-field-radio .x-field-mask::after, .x-select-overlay .x-item-selected.x-list-item::after
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 10px;
bottom: 0;
content: '3';
font-family: 'Pictos';
font-size: 1.6em;
text-align: right;
line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

`

you can change "right:10px" to "left:10px".

in my app, i put this css code in index.html

```
.x-checkmark-base, .x-field-checkbox .x-field-mask::after, .x-field-radio .x-field-mask::after, .x-select-overlay .x-item-selected.x-list-item::after
{
right:auto !important;
left:10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

insert the following, in your css

```
.x-field .x-input-checkbox::after,  .x-field .x-input-checkbox:checked::after
 {
     right:auto;
 }
```